# Prevent touch events to GMSMapView

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a UIImageView that I'm laying on top of a GMSMapView to display a map.  I'd like to disable touch sensing on the MapView so that I can do something different inside the UIImageView.

## 1 - is it possible to prevent a lower layer from receiving touch events?  I've made sure the UIImageView is definitely the topmost view.

## 2 - why are "touchesbegan" and the other touch delegates not getting called by my root view controller just because a mapsview is present?

Answer (score 2):

Use the SDK's setUserInteractionEnabled method to disable interaction.  This will allow the root view controller to start receiving touch events again.